# NestJS and typescript config strong types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have a main config in my app, which is expressed trough environment variables (process.env). How can i expose it with next JS as one object? In the example below, i can get value by the key. But i passing a string, no typescript comes into play here.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { envVarsValidator } from "../interfaces/Config";

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: envVarsValidator,
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  getHello(): string {
    return this.configService.get<string>('hello'); // not what i need;
  }

}
```

Pseudocode for what i need:

```js
export class SomeService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  someLogic(): any {
    const port = this.configService.config.port;
// what i need is one main config object with highlighting properties avaliable on this object via typescript
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

see https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#configuration-namespaces

e.g.

config/database.config.ts JS

```
export default registerAs('database', () => ({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT || 5432
}));
```

and inject typed object

```
constructor(
  @Inject(databaseConfig.KEY)
  private dbConfig: ConfigType<typeof databaseConfig>,
) {}
```

Comment: Can you add a way to do almost same thing when you wanna use it inside the useFactory? [is this the only way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72945143/8784518)?

Answer (score 3):

In your class's constructor, as you inject `ConfigService`, parametrize it with the interface representing the shape of your config.

```
interface MyConfig {
  port: number;
  dbConnectionString: string;
}

class AppService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService<MyConfig>) {}
}
```

That will change the type of `configService.get` to `ConfigService<MyConfig, false>.get<any>(propertyPath: keyof MyConfig): any`. You'll still be passing in strings, but thanks to `propertyPath: keyof MyConfig`, TypeScript will now check whether the string represents a key of `MyConfig`.

So if you try to do something like `configService.get('nonexistentConfigProp')`, you'll get `TS2345: Argument of type '"nonexistentConfigProp"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof MyConfig'` which is exactly what you want to happen.

Please note that you can also parametrize `get` further, e.g. `get<T>` for it to return `T | undefined` instead of `any`. If you'd like it to return just `T` because you have previously validated the config object and you know its properties are defined, you can parametrize `ConfigService` further with a second boolean parameter called `WasValidated`, i.e. `ConfigService<MyConfig, true>`. Then `get<T>` will return just `T`.

Comment: It doesn't work for nested props like get('db.host')

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a typescript type object on the class level.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

// add this type with your allowed values
type MyType = {
  hello: string;
  someOtherValue: string;
};

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService<MyType>) {} // <-- add the type here

  getHello(): string {
    return this.configService.get<string>('hello1'); // this should now show an TS error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with a slightly more boilerplaty approach of wrapping nest's ConfigService with my own and exporting it as a part of a module (along with other common services I use often in my app), like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  get MY_CONFIG_STRING() {
    // this reads the value from your .env
    return this.configService.get<string>('MY_CONFIG_STRING')!
  }

  get MY_CONFIG_Number() {
    // this reads the value from your .env
    return this.configService.get<number>('MY_CONFIG_NUMBER')!
  }
}
```

The user side is sweet and simple:

```
export class DoSomethingService {
  constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService) {}

  doSomething() {
    console.log(this.configurationService.MY_CONFIG_VALUE)
  }

}
```

Just make sure to bootstrap Nest's config service in your ConfigurationService module like so:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { ConfigurationService } from './configuration.service'

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    ConfigurationService,
  ],
  exports: [ConfigurationService],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

We've developed the [nest-typed-config](https://github.com/Nikaple/nest-typed-config) module to solve the issue.

First you need to create your config model:

```
// config.ts
export class Config {
    @IsString()
    public readonly host!: string;

    @IsNumber()
    public readonly port!: number;
}
```

Register `TypedConfigModule` in `AppModule`:

```
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypedConfigModule, fileLoader } from 'nest-typed-config';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Config } from './config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypedConfigModule.forRoot({
            schema: Config,
            load: fileLoader(),
            isGlobal: true,
        }),
    ],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And that's it! You can inject `Config` in any service now:

```
// app.service.ts
import { Config } from './config';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(private readonly config: Config) {}

    show() {
        // Full TypeScript support
        console.log(`http://${this.config.host}:${this.config.port}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have configured this module for dotenv file but I am getting *Error: Configuration is not valid:
  - config DATABASE_PORT does not match the following rules:
    - isNumber: DATABASE_PORT must be a number conforming to the specified constraints, current config is `"3306"`* 
content of .env file are `DATABASE_PORT=3306`

Comment: Fixed it by using the normalize function.

Answer (score 0):

Just create you own service wrapped over default and use it:

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { ConfigSchema } from "src/other/configuration";

@Injectable()
export class TypedConfigService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService<ConfigSchema>) {}

  get<T extends keyof ConfigSchema>(key: T) {
    return this.configService.get(key) as ConfigSchema[T];
  }
}
```